# an elementary proof without using K-convexity constant?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times d$ matrix $(n\gg d)$ with orthonormal columns, and $g\sim N(0,I_d)$. I wish to show that

$$
\mathbb{E}\sup_{x:\|Ax\|_1 = 1} \langle g,x\rangle \lesssim \sqrt{\log d}\cdot \max_{1\leq i\leq n} (\sum_j A_{ij}^2)^{\frac12}.
$$

I understand that this can be shown via the notion of K-convexity constant and the fact that the constant is $C\sqrt{\log d}$ for $d$-dimensional spaces, which uses the bound on the constant in Kahane's inequality.

Is there a proof without using such notions, or more elementary? For instance, let $T = \{x: \|Ax\|_1 = 1\}$, then the left-hand side of the inequality would be bounded by $\gamma_2(T, \|\cdot\|_2)$, is there an easy way to upper bound this quantity?

Comment: Can you check your inequality? It is not homogeneous: if $A$ is replaced by $tA$ the LHS is multiplied by $1/t$, and the RHS by $t$.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Sorry, let me say $A$ has *orthonormal* columns not just orthogonal.